# How to show app world in my BlackBerry application?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-world

How to lunch app world(BlackBerry-Market place) with in my BlackBerry application. Please guide me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at these instructions, How To - Interface with the BlackBerry App World

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1573156/How_To_-_Interface_with_the_BlackBerry_App_World.html?nodeid=1947155&vernum=0